# Can I get the style object and Get the property of it?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I wanted to use javascript addin's to get the style object and get some proerties of it for example maybe paragraph property and get the indentation of this specific style but I cant get to the style object and get the property of it. I know that there is a collection of every style in document but I cant get any properties of those. There is way to change style in selected range but it could be very fine if I could get style from the range maybe and like i said erlier get some properties of it.

This is code in Word VBA that is example of property i want to see value of:

`documents("[file_name]").Styles([index]).ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent`

We can set the value to any variable:

```
Dim var As Integer/Long
Let var = documents("[file_name]").Styles([index]).ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent
```

Comment: The next batch of updates to the Word JavaScript APIs will include a lot of enhanced support for styles. They should be available for preview soon.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the office.js API for Word does not currently (v. 1.4) provide any Style *objects* with the kind of properties that you are used to seeing via the Object Model that VBA uses. All it lets you do is get the style *names* (localized and built-in) associated with another object such as a range, a paragraph, or various style properties associated with a table.

i.e. at the moment, the only way you would be able to get detailed style information would probably be to retrieve the document's XML and interpret that. Hard, I suspect.

I think that probably answers your question but in case you were looking for code to retrieve a style, to get the *style name* of a range, say, is straightforward, e.g. in Script Lab you can start with one of the basic JavaScript samples and modify its run function so it looks like this:

```
function run() {
  return Word.run(function(context) {
    var range = context.document.getSelection();
    range.load("style");
    
    return context.sync().then(function() {
      console.log('The selected style was "' + range.style + '".');
    });
  });
}
```

Precisely which style name you get depends on the range - if you select two paragraphs with different styles, the style name will be "", and so on.

Comment: Thank you its really helpfull. I have one more thing bcs I am new in this and i dont really know how to get document xml and maybe edit it or include it in code and get from it any values.

Comment: @ItsJustPaperMan to *get* the ooxml, perhaps start somewhere like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/officedev/pnp-officeaddins/word-get-set-edit-ooxml/. But understanding how to interpret or use that ooxml is another thing altogether.

Comment: Okay. I will try to get to this level. Thanks anyway you were very helpfull.